# force the flutter to use http instead of https in the app

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

my website does not have the SSL certificate so i got privacy problem each time i open the website, i am trying to use it in my flutter app but the app keeps using https that makes it not working
the problem in the following line,
`

```
static Uri configUrl(String url){
  var uri = Uri.http(apiConfig.api_url.replaceAll("/api/", "").replaceAll("https://", "").replaceAll("http://", ""), '/api/'+url+apiConfig.api_token+"/"+apiConfig.item_purchase_code +"/", {"s":"https"});

  return uri;
}
```

`

how can i change it to force the app to use http instead of https

i tried to use `Uri.http` instead of `Uri.https` and  `replaceAll("https://", "http://")` but nothing works

Comment: You can't make a secure connection if your site has not an SSL certificate, so only changing the url would not work

Comment: Maybe your backend server redirects all http addresses to https

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTTP client for communicating with an HTTP server.

Here's the implementation that you need to that Globally in your project main.dart file.

```
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
      HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
     }
```

Second step is to make the clear demonstration of this class, Make sure you do that in the main file, inside the main function for running the app.

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}
```